# Converting an Array to a SharedArray in Julia

Tags: julia

Simple Question. Let's say I have some Array:

```
julia> A = randn(3,3)
```

How can I turn this into a [`SharedArray`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/) so that it can be accessed/altered by parallel processes? As of now, there is no convert function implemented to do this automatically:

```
julia> SharedArray(A)
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching ...
```

I think the only way to do this is to use the constructor (and pass an appropriate initialization function, `init`):

```
SharedArray(T::Type, dims::NTuple; init=false, pids=Int[])
```

Comment: The expected way to do conversion is by direct call to `convert()` function, and passing source as an argument to constructor may not lead to the desired answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different conversion methods have already been implemented in **[sharedarray.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/sharedarray.jl)**. The one bellow defines how an array is converted to a SharedArray of the same element type:

`convert(::Type{SharedArray},A::Array)=(S=SharedArray(eltype(A),size(A));copy!(S,A))`

So, one could convert an array to a SharedArray simply by calling convert function:

```
julia> src=ones(2,4)
2x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> convert(SharedArray,src)
2x4 SharedArray{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one simple way to do it. Not sure if there is something better:

```
addprocs(3) # add worker processes
A = randn(3,4)
S = SharedArray(Float64, size(A))
S[:] = A[:] # works because A is defined on master process 1
```